# Database migration with two context in Asp.Net Core (SQL Server on Docker)

Tags: entity-framework, docker, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, database-migration

I have two Context in my Application.
One in `WebApi Project -> ApiContext (inherited from IdentityDbContext)`
and another one in `Infrastructure -> Context`.

I use Official images for Microsoft SQL Server on Linux for Docker Engine (`microsoft/mssql-server-linux`).

I wrote a `DbFactory`. Below you can find my codes.

**ApiContext:**

```
internal class ApiContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApiContext(DbContextOptions<ApiContext> options) : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureDeleted();
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

**Context**

```
internal class Context : DbContext
{
    public Context(DbContextOptions<Context> options) : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    public DbSet<Reservation> Reservations { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Table>().ToTable("Table");
    }
}
```

In my infrastructure project, I have as I said **DbFactory**

```
public class DesignTimeDbContextFactory<T> : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<T>
    where T : DbContext
{
    public T CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        IConfigurationRoot configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
            .Build();
        var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<T>();
        var connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
        builder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
        var dbContext = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(
            typeof(T),
            builder.Options);
        return dbContext;
    }
}
```

and

```
internal class ContextDesignTimeDbContextFactory : DesignTimeDbContextFactory<Context>
{
}
```

and in WebApi project

```
internal class ApiContextDesignTimeDbContextFactory : DesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApiContext>
{
}
```

I would like to use entity framework core migration. 
When I run

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate
```

in ApiProject (using cmd)
I get

> More than one DbContext was found. Specify which one to use. Use the
>   '-Context' parameter for PowerShell commands and the '--context'
>   parameter for dotnet commands.

Could you please tell me how can I handle database migration with two contexts on Asp.Net Core 2.0 and EntityFrameworkCore 2 and docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify which DbContext you use:

```
dotnet ef migrations add ArbitraryMigrationName -c YourDbContextName
```

Comment: So should I use that command twice, once for ApiContext and once for Context, right?

Comment: Yes, exactlly like that.

Comment: I am having this same situation. When I run this, it says that the docker image doesn't have .NET SDK. Am I supposed to install .NET SDK to my container first? This seems like overkill to me.